# I have to restart sshd every time I reboot

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, sshd

I have an arch machine that I use as a local server. It used to be that every time I rebooted it (which was not often), I had to login and enter `# dhcpcd net0`. After that, I could ssh into it from my main computer just fine. Now I have done `# systemctl enable dhcpcd@net0.service` which works great for connecting to the internet, but has broken ssh. I can ping the server, but when I try to ssh in I get `ssh: connect to host nas port 22: Connection refused`. It only works once I login and run `# systemctl restart sshd`.

Comment: Read the journal entries for each of those services (dhcpcd & sshd) *before* and *after* you restart them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo systemctl enable sshd.socket
```

To enable service to run on boot.

Comment: I already ran systemctl enable sshd.service

Comment: sshd doesn't use socket activation, it has a daemon process.

Comment: @Bratchley `sshd` CAN use socket activation (see `-i` switch for `sshd`. We have this possibility in RHEL and Fedora). But it does not change the fact that this does not generally answer the question nor does explain the behaviour of the command snippet.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. Sorry for my previous comment.